# android 4.0 Ice Cream sandwich Status Bar notification issue

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am using Notification in my project.I am facing problem on ICS is that when two different notifications are received then ICS shows the one which come last but not the one which came first.but I am able to see both in notification window.

This is not observed in emulator but its not working on ICS device.
is it because of the ICS is clubbing same type notification together? how to avoid it?

has anybody seen this before?? help

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you clarify ".. ICS shows the one which come last but not the one which came first", where can't you see the previous notification?

Comment: @Soham i meant notification which comes last is shown in status bar but one which came earlier is not seen 
to varify this i sent 2 notifications "first" and "second" but only "second" is shown in status bar not "first" but i can see them both in notification window after dragging down status bar that means both notifications are received but only last one is seen which is not in case for 2.2

Comment: got it, yup, so you are talking about the full statusbar-wide notification like so http://developer.android.com/design/media/notifications_pattern_phone_ticker.png